# analyze tcp payload of each tcp packet in `pcap` files

Tags: networking, pcap, libpcap, tcpdump

I have a lot of `pcap` files
in each pcap file there are some tcp packets
I want to the following steps:

1 filter the pcap file to get expected tcp packets(if with tshark, the filter is like  `tcp.srcport==80 and tcp.dstport==20000`). The tcp data in each tcp packet are of tens of bytes,

```
  1) the first 2 bytes are sequence number
  2) the second 2 bytes indicate a length: **n**
  3) the following **n** bytes are random (if **n** is 2, then there are 2 random bytes)
  4) immediately after the **n** bytes is an IP address
```

2 from each tcp packet, I want to get the source IP and the IP address string as mentioned in `4)`

Above all, I just want to get an IP pair from each tcp packet, the source IP is easy to be obtained from tshark, but the IP address in the tcp data needs some effort

are there any good source code snippets or good ways that can be used for my target?
thanks!